# Logical Private VS Physical Private

Tags: c++, private, encapsulation

I have a simple program :

```
class Element
{
public:
    Element(void) { m_iVal = 56789;}
    ~Element(void) {};
private :
    int m_iVal;
};
```

The variable `m_iVal` is private, which poses restrictions from a conceptual point of view (inheritance, ...).
However, although private, access to it content is still possible.

[image]

Is there a way to prohibit physical access to a varibal (or a heap area) so that any access to this private area will cause a memory access violation.

Comment: What you are doing is undefined behavior.

Comment: `private` is not to make it impossible to access the member, but it is to prevent you from accidentally accessing it. If you still want to access it you can, but why would you? (btw your code accessing it has undefined behavior, and you cannot prevent someone from doing that, though there are also legal ways)

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov I am not sure this is undefined behavior in C++. At least in C, it is required that the address of the structure to be the same as the address of its first member.

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov  I am perfectly aware of this but I wish to prohibit "any search" in an instance of my object by another local third-party program or DLL ...

Comment: @lvella "_At least in C, it is required that the address of the structure to be the same as the address of its first member._" If I remember correctly: in C++, this is correct for POD-structures. All of structures in C are POD, but not all structures in C++ are POD.

Comment: no matter how you write your code you cannot prevent others from writing code that has ub

Comment: @Landstalker "but I wish to prohibit "any search" in an instance of my object by another local third-party program or DLL " - I'm pretty sure you cannot do that. You just have to write your code such that it behaves correctly (or terminates) in the event someone does that. You can't prevent it. There's no magic "make my code hacker proof" switch you can flip.

Comment: @Landstalker "I wish to prohibit "any search" in an instance of my object by another local third-party program or DLL" I am sure every developer of a pirated software would love that. So far, that has proven very hard to do, but you might try it with Trusted Computing.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I agree with you. I'm looking for a fair way to "deter" search in data LOCALLY (Relative to my dev environment, not absolutely ...)

Comment: @JesperJuhl; @Ivella  : Yes, i agree

Comment: @Landstalker What you want is a unicorn. You cannot have that. You can have a pony. It's no unicorn but it looks similar. Doesn't do magic though. Sorry.

Comment: @JesperJuhl yes, of course, Thanks.

Comment: "deter"? declaring the variable as `private` is the way to do that. If someone writes code like in your access-the-private example then they just get what they deserve

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes,  I will content myself with this

Comment: @idclev463035818 "deter" in the sense that I must prevent access for other modules developed in LOCAL (not by me). It is not a question of preventing access in an absolute way because it is not possible

Comment: Are you looking to hide certain data from debugger? kinda hard coded password ?

Comment: @TruthSeeker something like that yes. it is not really passwords but rather sensitive data which is not yet processed by other encryption modules (hash functions, ...) which hide a certain outside visibility. But for the interior (our modules) I try to prohibit physical access because it will avoid me to developpe a new software protection layer internally

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/926192/4139593) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39483519/4139593) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830845/4139593) can help you.

Comment: @TruthSeeker thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Access protection; `public`/`protected`/`private` is *purely* a compile time thing. It exists to prevent simple errors. It it *not* a run-time protection mechanism.

Once your code has passed the first stage of your compiler, `public`, `protected` and `private` no longer exists at all. And in the generated binary, there's no trace of those what-so-ever.

Comment: I agree with you.